# Unexpected error in connected link

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I have connected to a json file on another website. But I get an error in the connected json file, saying that, I don't have access.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  in the link that I have connected.
```

How do I solve this kind of problem?

```
$.getJSON("http://curvefever.com/achtung/match/16911009/jsoncallback=?", function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: What is your JSON file returning?  It seems to be returning HTML.

Comment: Yep, the URL above returns HTML. Trying to treat HTML as JSON isn't going to work...

Comment: What is the solution then?

Comment: Do you own/manage curvefever.com? Who gave you that URL?

Comment: I got it on their website. I just put json after the link and got data in to JSON format

Comment: But that's the point, **it's not returning JSON**. Why do you think putting jsoncallback=? on the end will turn it into JSON?

Comment: According to many website I had to put  jsoncallback=? to connect the link. I received this message: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:... Before I got error but now I get this!

Comment: Putting `jsoncallback=?` on the URL does not magically return JSON automatically. Contact the website to ask if they provide data in JSON format for you. The above will not work.

Comment: This link: http://curvefever.com/achtung/match/16911009/json
aren't this link in json format?

Comment: @user3478007: That is, yes, but because of the same-origin policy, you can't access that from your page.  JSONP needs to be supported on the *server*.  If the server doesn't support JSONP, then you can try CORS, but again, that's something the *server* needs to support.  Chances are, you're gonna have to make a proxy script on your server to get the JSON for you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably returned json string has contains multiple slash characters. To avoid this;

Put this code where you get the json string.

```
yourjsonvariable.replace('/\\/g', '');
```

Comment: You should be fixing the JSON on the server, *before* it gets to the JavaScript.

Comment: $.getJSON("http://curvefever.com/achtung/match/16911009/jsoncallback=?", function (data) {
  alert(data);
 });

Comment: Put these codes into your question please. So we can understand and help you and put the returned data so we can see what is returning.

Comment: How do I fix the JSON server`?

Comment: @user3478007: That link does returns neither JSON nor JSONP.